# Angularjs cannot post big data by $http

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

```
var data = $.param({
    json: JSON.stringify(formData)
});

$http.post("/test", data).success(function(data, status) {
    $scope.hello = data;
})
```

I tested it if the data is 32K, it will fail:

```
{ 
    "data": null,
    "status": 0,
    "config": {
        "method": "POST",
        "transformRequest": [null],
        "transformResponse": [null],
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/test",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        },
        "data":....
```

and my test server which is a ruby server will not get any request.

How can I solve it?

Comment: try **angular.toJson** instead of JSON.stringify

Comment: Did you checked whether URL of the server is correct ? And did you tried sending small data ? Any errors in console while sending the request ?

Comment: Yes, URL is correct, small data can be sent. And server can handle big data post(verified by `curl`)

Comment: Did you check whether `JSON.stringify(32K data)` is properly converted to JSON. Try printing them separately before making a post request to check whether the stringify actually works well.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Post data limits could be set on the server that the file is uploaded to.